# Automated Unit Testing of Android test project in TeamCity

Tags: android, unit-testing, intellij-idea, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I have an IntelliJ project with a shared build configuration for running a juni3 android test module. I want to test run this in TeamCity. I used the teamcity 'wizard' which parses my .idea folder for the list of shared run configurations checked in. I verified that my shared configurations are committed to my source repository.

I was able to build my apk as specified by an Artificat defined in my IntelliJ project. i set that as a TeamCity build artifact, and the apk builds fine.

I selected my test configuration, but when I go to run it, I get the following:

```
IntelliJ IDEA project does not contain shared run configuration with name [MyConfigName]
```

How can I run automated unit tests for android in teamcity via my intellij project?

I'm on TeamCity 8.1.3